# Select parent based on attribute of most recent child element

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

I'm writing a simple membership application. I have two models, `Member` and `Membership`.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

A `member` holds information like name and date of birth, a `membership` holds the date the membership was applied for, the date it started, the date it expires etc. Once a membership expires, the member can renew it, which creates a *new* membership. This means that each member can have multiple memberships, although only the latest will be their current, valid membership.

I now want to retrieve, for example, all members whose membership has expired. I can't just do something like

```
@members = Member.joins(:memberships).where('memberships.expires < ?', Time.now)
```

as this will include any current members who have had memberships in the past. What I really need to do is to be able to join to *only* the most recent of a member's memberships and base the query on that. I'm new to Rails though so struggling a bit with this - help or ideas very much appreciated.

EDIT: Obviously this is the kind of thing that's not difficult to do in plain old SQL, but I was hoping there'd be some nice Rails way to do it (other than just pasting the SQL in).

I would also rather not add another column to either of the tables just to make the queries I want to do possible. It's messy, I shouldn't have to do it, and will most likely cause problems down the line.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844037/activerecord-nested-select-can-i-do-it-without-manual-sql

Comment: Thanks for the link. As I say though, doing it in SQL isn't the problem. I was hoping to be able to do it in a Rails-like way, still getting the benefit of abstracting away the SQL. From various answers it's starting to look like that's not possible.

Comment: Abstraction is nice. The problem in this case is that ActiveRecord (and other similar abstraction layers) seem to support only a very limited subset of SQL capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions. I've voted them up rather than accepting them as I don't feel they quite cover what I want, but what I'm going to do has certainly benefitted from them.

I still feel that SQL should be avoided if possible (for all the reasons I've already mentioned in comments), but I think in this case it can't, so I've decided to define a named scope for the Member model like this:

EDIT: I originally defined this as the default scope - however I have decided to heed the warning from KandadaBoggu on complex default scopes, so have made it a named scope instead. The query is also a bit more complicated than others described to cope with excluding renewed memberships (where the start date is in the future) when a currently active membership exists. Thanks again to KandadaBoggu for the bones of the query and hint on avoiding N+1 selects.

```
scope :with_membership, lambda { 
select('members.*, m.applied AS applied, m.paid AS paid, m.start AS start, m.expiry as expiry').
joins("INNER JOIN (
  SELECT m3.*
  FROM memberships m3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships m5 
  ON m3.member_id = m5.member_id 
  AND m5.created_at > m3.created_at
  AND m5.expiry > #{sanitize(Time.now)}
  WHERE m3.expiry > #{sanitize(Time.now)}
  AND m5.id IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT m1.*
  FROM   memberships m1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships m2 
  ON m1.member_id = m2.member_id 
  AND m2.created_at > m1.created_at 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships m4 
  ON m1.member_id = m4.member_id 
  AND m4.expiry > #{sanitize(Time.now)}
  WHERE  m2.id IS NULL AND m4.id IS NULL
  ) m 
  on (m.member_id = members.id)") }
```

I've seen prettier bits of code. But my rationale is this - if you're going to have to have a horrible bit of SQL like this, you might as well have it in only one place rather than repeated all over the place for every different query you might need (like expired members, members who haven't paid yet etc etc).

With the above scope in place, I can just treat the extra membership columns as normal columns on `Member`, and write nicely simple queries like this:

```
#expired
Member.with_membership.find :all, :conditions => ['expires < ?', Time.now ]

#current
Member.with_membership.find :all, :conditions => ['started < ? AND expires > ?', Time.now, Time.now ]

#pending payment
Member.with_membership.find :all, :conditions => ['applied < ? AND paid IS NULL', Time.now ]
```

To briefly justify accepting my own answer rather than one of the other, very useful answers, I want to point out that this was never a question about how to get the 'greatest n per group' (although this is a component of it). It was about how to best deal with this kind of query in the specific environment of Rails, with the specific problem of members with multiple memberships where only one is active at any one time, and with a number of similar queries that all need fields from this single active membership.

That's why I think using a named scope in this way is, ultimately, the best answer to the question. Put up with the hideous SQL query, but have it in one place only.

Comment: The `default_scope` should be simple at most it can contain `order` or may be filter for some state flag ( eg: by default you want to filter deleted rows). When you  add `joins` and `select` clauses to `default_scope` you are asking for trouble. Few months down the line when you are trying to debug some issue you(or your team member) will forget that there is a default scope on the `Member` class. At least that's what happened in my team.

Comment: The query used in the `default_scope` has a correlated subquery. Server will run in to the N+1 query problem.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about keeping the `default_scope` simple - I can see how it could cause problems. However, I still think in this case you gain a lot of simplicity from using it (comparing to repeating the same query throughout the code). I also think the membership dates of a member are such a fundamental part of this kind of system that it's reasonable to expect developers to understand and remember this case.

Comment: And yes, you're right about the N+1 query problem. If you can show me a way to rewrite it - bearing in mind I have the restrictions of MySQL (something I can't change) then I would be very grateful. The only way I can see to do this would be to denormalise the table (as described in other answers to this question). Given the size of the organisation I'm writing for (and the number of members they're likely to have) I think the best course of action is to accept that the N+1 selects are going to happen and it probably doesn't matter, then denormalise if it becomes a problem.

Comment: Assuming you have an index on `member_id` column in `memberships` table, the GROUP BY solution I suggested in my original answer will avoid N+1 issues. The solution is DB agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think of it logically.

> all members whose most recent membership has expired

Is actually the same as

> all members who have no active membership

In the latter case you can do it in SQL like so

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM memberships
  WHERE members.id = memberships.member_id
  AND   memberships.expires > #{Time.now}
)
```

You can achieve the same with Active Record

```
Member.where(["NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM memberships
  WHERE members.id = memberships.member_id
  AND   memberships.expires > ?
)", Time.now])
```

Now that is quite nasty,
but that is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: note, I'm not going to discuss the merits of subqueries. It depends on your database But for simple use-cases, it's clear the intent, and works fine.

Comment: That is quite nasty, you're right. I guess I was hoping there was some nice, clean, Railsy way to do it.

Comment: I'd look at it a different way. Use AASM, and set an "expired" state for Memberships. Then find all "active" memberships with an expired date, and join their members.

Comment: `EXISTS` is not nasty at all. Not sure if this query is correct answer for your question though.

Comment: Nor if it can be made look more elegant using only activerecord code.

Comment: I didn't mean that 'EXISTS' is nasty. As a SQL query it's pretty inoffensive. I just thought the whole point of things like ActiveRecord was to abstract away the database. Not necessarily making the query look more elegant (although this is always nice) but *decoupling* it from the implementation.

Comment: @Russell: Oh sorry, I misinterpreted you. I agree with you 100% on that. Pity that ActiveRecord (seems to) be offering "decoupling" (nice word) but only for a limited subset of SQL.

Comment: @ypercube Yeah it's a nice idea - but sometimes I get so fed up battling with one ORM framework or another trying to get it to spit out something that I know I could do in ten minutes in SQL that I wonder if it really is worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1- Group MAX**

You might get better results by using a `JOIN`.

```
Member.joins("JOIN (
     SELECT a.member_id, MAX(a.expires) expires_at
     FROM   memberships a
     GROUP BY a.member_id
     WHERE a.paid = 1 AND  a.expires IS NOT NULL
   ) b ON b.member_id = members.id
  ").
  where("b.expires < ?", Time.now)
```

**Approach 2 - LEFT JOIN**

```
Member.joins(
  "
    JOIN
    ( 
      SELECT m1.membership_id
      FROM   membership m1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN membership m2 
             ON m2.membership_id = m1.membership_id AND
                m2.expires IS NOT NULL AND
                m2.expires < m1.expires 
      WHERE  m2.expires IS NULL AND 
             m1.expires < #{sanitize(Time.now)}
    ) m ON m.membership_id = members.id
 "
)
```

**Approach 3 - Denormalization**

Better solution is to add a flag called `is_current` on the `memberships` table and set the default value to `true`.

```
class Membership

  after_create :reset_membership

  # set the old current to false    
  def reset_membership
    Membership.update_all({:is_current => false}, 
      ["member_id = ? AND id != ?", member_id, id])
  end
end

class Member
  has_many :memberships
  scope :recently_expired, lambda {
   { 
     :joins      => :memberships, 
     :conditions => [ "memberships.is_current = ? AND memberships.expires < ?", 
                       true, Time.now]
   }
  }
end
```

Now you can get the recently expired members as:

```
Member.recently_expired
```

Comment: I'm not sure I like the idea of adding an `is_current` flag. This effectively denormalises the table and means as soon as there's a failed update or a bug introduced which stops the flag being set properly, they get out of sync and I have bad data which could cause all sorts of problems and will need manually clearing up.

Comment: The table updates are done in one transaction so there is not question of phantom records. The denormalization is a valid technique after you have normalized your tables. The Rails functions like `Observer` is usually used to update dependent tables.

Comment: I have nothing against denormalisation per se - when it is applied appropriately - I just don't think it should be necessary here. Yes, the transaction will prevent the problem in the case you describe, but the simple fact is if you have the same data in two different places they are *going* to get out of sync. Somehow they always do. One piece of data in one place is never going to do that. So I use denormalisation when I have to, and when it's reasonably safe for data to get out of sync.

Comment: Thanks - and answer 2, unless I'm wrong, will avoid n+1 selects too? If so I will switch that in for the query I'm currently using.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't put enough info into the question to make this clear, but certain columns on `Membership` will sometimes be NULL - for example, if someone has applied for membership but hasn't paid yet, then their paid, started and expires dates will be NULL - so answer 1 won't work.

Comment: Add the filters to check for that condition.

Comment: I have updated my answers based on your last two comments. **PS**: 1,2 avoids N+1 issue.

Comment: I'd rather just do it a different way. Writing a query with what are essentially hacks in it so that it happens to return a bunch of columns that all happen to be from the same row is 10 squillion times more prone to error somewhere down the line than writing something that returns the specific row you're interested in. Even if it's slower, it's better. I like your second answer though and will probably use it - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a column past_expired in membership model and becomes true when the member add a new membership, so you can get easyly the last membership.

Answer (score 1):

Another SQL query that solves this [greatest-n-per-group] type problem would be the following. It joins the `members` and `memberships` tables using a complex condition that limits the join to the one row of memberships that has the latest expiration date:

```
SELECT members.*
     , m.applied AS applied
     , m.paid    AS paid
     , m.started AS started
     , m.expires AS expires
FROM 
    members
  INNER JOIN 
    memberships AS m
      ON m.id = ( SELECT m1.id
                  FROM memberships m1 
                  WHERE m1.member_id = members.id
                  ORDER BY m1.expires DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                )
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in MySQL (it was my first attempt) as you can't seem to reference tables from the parent query in the subquery as you do here with `WHERE m1.member_id = members.id`. Coming from Oracle this feels quite restrictive.

Comment: @Russell: This **does** work in MySQL. What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: What doesn't work is `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT 1)`. Perhaps you tried that road.

Comment: My apologies - it does. I don't have the code I was playing around with any more so I can't find out what I did wrong - I guess it was probably a typo that I misinterpreted as a lack of feature. Foolish.